# OS X 10.6: Cant unbundle VMWare software with git: does not look like a v2 bundle file

Tags: linux, macos, git, vmware-fusion

So I am using Mac OS X 10.6.8, I'm trying to download VMWare Player, there was no OS X specific bundle, only linux. I tried to unbundle the 32 bit linux with:

```
jdd:VMWare Me$ git clone VMware-Player-6.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle -b master ./VMWare
Cloning into ./VMWare...
error: '/Users/Me/VMWare/VMware-Player-6.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle' does not look like a v2 bundle file
fatal: Could not read bundle '/Users/Me/VMWare/VMware-Player-6.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle'.
jdd:VMWare Me$
```

and git version:

```
jdd:VMWare Me$ git --version
git version 1.7.5.4
jdd:VMWare Me$
```

I was trying to google, unsuccessfully, what a v2 bundle file is, what the expected type on OS X and linux are, to see the difference, and to see if there was a conversion tool. Any Ideas?